# Texts disappear (text rendering)

Tags: android, android-webview, textview

This is my first question on this forum.

I have a weird problem on Android platform. Currently our app is in closed beta and I have received few error reports of disappearing texts.

In practice, all the texts disappear in my app. In every Fragment, in every Activity. Also from Action Bar. Based on the reports, it seems that this occurs after using WebView, but I can not be sure if usage of the WebView has something to do with this issue.

I'm targeting the app >= 4.2 Android and received error reports from 4.2 to 4.4. Unfortunately I haven't been able to reproduce the problem.

This image shows you the problem. In the image should have texts in Action Bar (App name, Tab texts and also lot of texts in the view:[Screenshot of the problem](http://www.dropbox.com/s/mrse1ncuqrt9ff4/Notexts.png?dl=0)

Have you ever encountered this kind of problem and do you have any idea what might be the problem.

Thanks, Veikko

Comment: I experienced the same issue in my app but I can't reproduce it, happened when I replaced my main content fragment

Comment: Are you using custom fonts? You may be hitting https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=369401

Comment: No custom fonts in use. Thanks anyway!